# How to annotate a value of related filtered and aggregated object?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm

I have two objects:

**Course** (one) and **TeachingAssistantsNumberApprovalRequest** (many).

Each request has fields:

closedAt - time
status - (Approved, Pending, Rejected)
requestedNumberOfTAs - integer

As a result there is a table for **TeachingAssistantsNumberApprovalRequest**:

| course_id | status | closedAt | requestedNumberOfTAs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending | null | 3 |
| 1 | Approved | 9:40 21.04.23 | 2 |
| 1 | Approved | 3:40 19.04.23 | 3 |
| 1 | Rejected | 2:10 19.04.23 | 4 |
| 2 | Approved | 10:40 21.04.23 | 2 |
| 2 | Approved | 9:40 21.04.23 | 3 |
| 2 | Rejected | 3:40 19.04.23 | 4 |
| 2 | Rejected | 2:10 19.04.23 | 5 |

I need to annotate the **latest approved** requestedNumberOfTAs.

This is how I managed to do it with raw SQL:

```sql
select 
      web_course.*,
      CASE when ta_requested_number_approved.requested_tas > 0 then ta_requested_number_approved.requested_tas else 0 end as tas_request_approved
from web_course
left join (
            select
                web_course.id as course_id, 
                req."requestedNumberOfTAs" as requested_tas
                from web_course  
                left join web_numberoftaupdaterequest as req on req.course_id = web_course.id
                inner join (
                    select
                        web_course.id as id,
                        max(req."closedAt") as closed_at
                        from web_numberoftaupdaterequest as req 
                        inner join web_course on req.course_id = web_course.id 
                        where web_course.year = '{year}' and web_course.term = '{term}' and req.status = 'Pending' 
                        group by web_course.id order by web_course.id
                        ) as max_date on max_date.id = req.course_id and max_date.closed_at = req."closedAt"
            where web_course.year = '{year}' and web_course.term = '{term}' and req.status = 'Pending'
            order by  web_course.id
        ) as ta_requested_number_pending on ta_requested_number_pending.course_id = web_course.id
        inner join web_teaching on web_teaching.course_id = web_course.id
        where web_course.year = '{year}' and web_course.term = '{term}' and web_teaching.person_id = {request.user.id};
```

How do we do it in Django ORM? Specifically the aggregation over subset of entries in request table, because if there was only one approved request and others were marked as outdated or smth, it would have been just one line.

Django version 3.2.18, DB Postgres 14

Answer (score 0):

After some additional search and practice I found a solution through Subquery and OuterRef:

```py
latest_approved_subquery = NumberOfTAUpdateRequest.objects.filter(course=OuterRef('pk'),status='Approved').order_by('-closedAt').values('requestedNumberOfTAs')[:1]
latest_pending_subquery = NumberOfTAUpdateRequest.objects.filter(course=OuterRef('pk'),status='Pending').order_by('-closedAt').values('requestedNumberOfTAs')[:1]

prev_year_course = (Course.objects.filter(year=prev_year, term = term, code=course.code)
            .annotate(hired=Count('applications', filter=Q(applications__status='Hired')))
            .annotate(tas_request_approved=Subquery(latest_approved_subquery))
            .get()
        )
```